# Match phone number with spaces in a string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I have a string

```
Contact us on 01234 567890 for free.
```

And I need to wrap a span around the number.

I've searched various answers, and tried:

```
/([0-9\s]+)/
/([0-9[\s]]+)/
/([0-9[\s]*]+)/
```

But these all match the other spaces in the string... I need it to only match the space if it's inside the numbers.

Comment: Use https://github.com/giggsey/libphonenumber-for-php for phone number validation and formatting.

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan - I don't see a feature of that library that will extract a telephone number from a string...

Comment: What would be the expected output for the above example? Did you want to capture `01234 567890`?

Comment: @Lix my bad. There's the findNumbers() function in the original Java version. Not sure if it's in the PHP port or not.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a regular expression similar to this:

```
\d+\s\d+
```

What I'm doing here is:

- `\d+` - One or more digit characters
- `\s`  - One white space character
- `\d+` - One or more digit characters

Keep in mind that when using a regex like this, the format of your telephone number is very important. It needs to always follow the same format: `{{DIGITS}}{{WHITESPACE}}{{DIGITS}}`

Answer (score 0):

If your data always conforms to `01234 567890`, you can use `/[0-9]{5}\s[0-9]{6}/` 
<sub>([Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/_E2zFbM48NOhDVU4))</sub>

```
01234 567890    => matches
0123 4567890    => does not match
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated solution of Lix:

```
/\d+(\s+\d+)*/
```